# Passing keyword arguments with default values in a layered call

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

I am working on a python library where I want to give some flexibility to the user. I am facing below challenge.

Let's say I exposed the class `Client` to the user, which is defined like below:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self.file_obj = FileOpener(path = path)
```

And my `FileOpener` class is:

```
class FileOpener:
    def __init__(self, path='my/default/path'):
        # My logic 
        pass
```

In above code, the issue is, if the user initialized the `Client` object as `c = Client()`, my underlying `FileOpener` class receives `None` as the path. But I want that even if `None` is passed, it should pick the default path.

Here are few solutions for this problem that I came up with, but they are somewhat flawed:

0. The most basic approach - filter the arguments and pass only those which are not `None`. I don't want to put a if - else ladder or create any unnecessary `dict` to store the values. Its not maintainable / readable and new coders can mess up easily.
1. I can define the default value in `Client` class itself. If the user doesn't pass anything, it will receive the default value. The issue is, suppose I have multiple layers, and in future I want to change the default value, I will need to change it everywhere. Hence this approach is not maintainable at all.
2. Second thing that came to my mind was, using `**kwargs`, that I can pass easily to underlying objects. This will not pass `None` by default if user didn't explicitly pass it. But now my user doesn't know what args my class is taking. He will need to go through the docs every time and won't be able to take advantage of his code editor (example - in VS Code you can use auto complete).

I want to understand if there is any standard approach for resolving this issue. Or any suggestions to get rid of the flaws in my approach. I want to have a maintainable solution so that if anyone in future comes to contribute, he can understand just by looking at the code and doesn't mess up.

Comment: In the `__init__` of `FileOpener`, you could do: `path = path or 'my/default/path'`. That way it does what you want even if the supplied `path` param is `None`.

Comment: @slothrop it is a good approach. But if have to do this, I don't understand the purpose of default values.

Comment: The default values would work fine in your `**kwargs` approach for example, but as you say that's not so great for intellisense. There are different valid approaches, but they have tradeoffs.

Comment: @slothrop yes correct. Btw I was looking at `requests` library. I am not sure how, but they have used `**kwargs` approach but still VSCode (am sure other IDEs also) intellisense is providing auto complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with another approach, which is maintainable and flexible. Though it still doesn't make the default value of keyword args useful. It just makes them optional. Use a class attribute to define the default path in the underlying `FileOpener` class. This way, the default value is centralized and easily modifiable. Here's an example:

```
class FileOpener:
    default_path = 'my/default/path'

    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self.path = path or self.default_path
        # my logic here
        pass

class Client:
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        self.file_obj = FileOpener(path=path)
```

This approach allows you to set the default path in one place (`FileOpener` class) and avoids cluttering the `Client` class with default values. It's maintainable, readable, and provides a clear structure for future contributors.

Now, if you want to change the default path, you only need to update it in the `FileOpener` class. This design has better code maintainability and readability without sacrificing flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

> even if `None` is passed, it should pick the default path.

If you have control over `FileOpener` I would suggest following approach

```
class FileOpener:
    def __init__(self, path='my/default/path'):
        if path is None:
            path = 'my/default/path'
        # logic 
        pass
```

observe that default path appears twice, but both are contained in single method. Problem might arise if someone else will just change one of them, to detect that I suggest furnishing your code with test case which will check if relevant behavior is same for not giving `path` and giving `None`, see [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) for common way of providing tests in `python`.

Comment: To avoid the duplication, an alternative would be to have `path=None` as the default parameter. But that's somewhat at the cost of clarity in documentation, intellisense etc.

Comment: @Daweo I don't see any use of declaring default value of `path` in args in this approach.